# SQL (Oracle) Joins when column results are slightly different

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to join 2 tables on a similar column where the data is slightly different between columns. An example:

Table1

```
Key_ID
______

12345678
12345679
12345671
12345672
```

Table2

```
Doc_Num
_______

Z12345678
Z12345679
Z12345671
Z12345672
```

These are the only columns that are relatable between the 2 tables. I need to join them in order to return data from different columns from Table 2. For example,

```
SELECT DocTitle, DocDate
FROM Table2
RIGHT JOIN Table1
ON Table2.Doc_Num = Table1.Key_ID
```

So my main question is how do I join the two tables when there's a "Z" in front of each of the data points I'm trying to join?

Please forgive my ignorance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select ...
from table1 t1
 right join table2 t2 on t1.key_id = to_number(substr(t2.doc_num,2));
```

Comment: This avoids problems when the Z becomes another letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DocTitle, DocDate
FROM Table2
RIGHT JOIN Table1
ON Table2.Doc_Num = 'Z' || Table1.Key_ID
```

or

```
SELECT DocTitle, DocDate
FROM Table2
RIGHT JOIN Table1
ON substr(Table2.Doc_Num, 2) = Table1.Key_ID
```

both will work